# How do i build JPQL Query on join table?

Tags: java, sql, orm, jpql

I'm trying to write a JPQL query to get the list of ingredients of a pizza from the following tables

```
pizza
+----+----------------+------+------------+--------------+
| id | nom            | prix | disponible | categorie_id |
+----+----------------+------+------------+--------------+
|  1 | Margherita     |  950 |          1 |            1 |
|  2 | Regina         | 1200 |          1 |            1 |
|  3 | Trois fromages | 1450 |          1 |            1 |
+----+----------------+------+------------+--------------+

ingredient
+----+-------------------+
| id | nom               |
+----+-------------------+
|  1 | fromage           |
|  2 | jambon            |
|  3 | champignons       |
+----+-------------------+

pizza_ingredient
+----------+---------------+
| pizza_id | ingredient_id |
+----------+---------------+
|        1 |             1 |
|        2 |             1 |
|        3 |             1 |
|        2 |             2 |
|        2 |             3 |
+----------+---------------+
```

From the following entities

Pizza.java

```java
@Entity
public class Pizza {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Categorie categorie;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name  = "pizza_ingredient",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "pizza_id"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ingredient_id"))
    private List<Ingredient> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
```

Ingredient.java

```java
@Entity
public class Ingredient {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Pizza pizza;
```

I've been trying several queries but including the following but i keep getting `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException` or similar errors

```java
public List<Ingredient> findIngredients(String pizzaNom) {
        return em.createQuery("SELECT i FROM Pizza p RIGHT JOIN p.ingredient i WHERE i.id = p.id ", Ingredient.class)
                .getResultList();
    }
```

I'm not really comfortable yet with join queries and jpql so every ressources I've found online so far has made me even more confused about what to to. Any help or ressource would be appreciated.

Comment: First, you need to fix your mapping. Your bidirectional association is not mapped correctly. You actually have two independent unidirectional associations. Once that is fixed, all you need is `select i from Pizza p join p.ingredients i where p.nom = :nom`.

Comment: @JBNizet Do yout think I should use the mappedBy annotation with a ManyToMany relation to relate the ingredients and the pizza ?

Comment: A pizza has many ingredients. An ingredient is on many pizzas. So yes, it's a many-to-many. And yes, in every bidirectional association, one side must be the owner side, and the other must be the inservse side and use the mappedBy attribute.